# WordPress Tag Page Hook?

Tags: tags

Is there any hook for a tag page, so I can alter it's content before outputting?

Comment: Do you mean wp-admin page or front-end tag archive? What exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: front-end only.

Comment: Duplicate question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12640/wordpress-tag-page-hook/12650#12650

Answer (score 3):

There is a conditional called :

```
is_tag
```

//From the codex

```
is_tag();
// When any Tag archive page is being displayed.

is_tag('mild');
// When the archive page for tag with the slug of 'mild' is being displayed.

is_tag(array('sharp','mild','extreme'));
// Returns true when the tag archive being displayed has a slug of either "sharp", "mild", or "extreme".
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag

Answer (score 1):

Archive pages are not generated by some specific function, but are produced by processing template file from your theme.

For tag archive page see [Template Hierarchy > Tag display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Tag_display) to determine which file in your theme could be it.

If theme you are using comes from official repository and likely to be updated it's good practice to create [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for it, so that your tweaks survive update.